# How to set shard key with MongoDB Scala driver

Tags: mongodb, scala

I would like to programmatically enable sharding for a MongoDB database and set a shard key using the MongoDB Scala driver.

```
val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
val db = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydatabase")
val views = db.getCollection("mycollection")
val obs = views.createIndex(ascending("x"))
```

I was wondering whether I can use:

```
db.runCommand(....)
```

But I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To enable sharding:

```
val db = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin")
val obs = db.runCommand(Document("enableSharding" -> "mydatabase"))
```

To shard a collection:

```
val db = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin")
val obs = db.runCommand(Document("shardCollection" -> "mydatabase.mycollection", "key" -> Document("xx" -> 1)))
```